# Where can I learn more about TransportSecurityWithMessageCredential in Silverlight 3

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight-3.0

I read [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/endpoint/archive/2009/03/20/what-s-new-with-web-services-in-silverlight-3-beta.aspx) about the new security options in Silverlight 3 and I was hoping someone could give me a link to more information on the TransportSecurityWithMessageCredential  option in Silverlight 3.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that it works in the same way as the equivalent WCF feature. You can read about that in [How to: Use Transport Security and Message Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789011.aspx) and [Chapter 7: Message and Transport Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949026.aspx) from the Scenarios and Implementation Guidance for WCF.